# Cannot find alphabet symbol

Tags: java, encryption, symbols

I'm trying to compile this code, but I get a `cannot find symbol - variable alphabet` . I don't understand why, because `alphabet` is being declared its value, that much is apparent. Is there something I'm missing here? My code aims to encrypt and decrypt messages, by using two keys that work by dividing up the letters so that every other letter is encrypted by one key starting from index 0, and every other letter from the index of 1 is encrypted by another key. These two sets of letters are calculated and weaved back together to form one decrypted string. In any case I'm only interested in finding out why I get a `cannot find symbol - variable alphabet`error. Any other suggestions for my code is appreciated but not necessary. Thanks!

```
public class CaesarCipherTwo {
    private int encrypt_key = 0;
    private int key1 = -1;
    private int key2 = -1;
    private CaesarCipher cc1;
    private CaesarCipher cc2;
    private void generateEncryptionLookup(){
        String alphabet_uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String alphabet_lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   

        String e_alphabet_uppercase = alphabet_uppercase.substring(encrypt_key) + alphabet_uppercase.substring(0,encrypt_key);
        String e_alphabet_lowercase = alphabet_lowercase.substring(encrypt_key) + alphabet_lowercase.substring(0,encrypt_key);


        alphabet = alphabet_uppercase + alphabet_lowercase;
        e_alphabet = e_alphabet_uppercase + e_alphabet_lowercase;
    }
     /**
     * Setter function for key used by cipher
     * @param key
     *            input key
    **/

    public void set_key(int key){
        this.encrypt_key = key;
        this.generateEncryptionLookup();

    }
    /**
     * Constructor - Takes in the two keys used for encryption. Use this constructor when you want to use this object for encryption (& then subsequent 
     * decryption of same string)
     * 
     * @param key1
     *              Key1 used in encryption process
     * @param key2
     *              Key2 used in encryption process
     */

    public CaesarCipherTwo(int key1, int key2){
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
        cc1 = new CaesarCipher();
        cc1.set_key(key1);
        cc2 = new CaesarCipher();
        cc2.set_key(key2);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor - To be used when you want to use this class for decryption & the method needs to figure out the decryption keys
     */
    public CaesarCipherTwo(){
        cc1 = new CaesarCipher();
        cc2 = new CaesarCipher();
    }

    /**
     * Takes a String as input and encrypts it using 2 keys
     * @param s 
     *          Input String
     * @return
     *          Encrypted String
     */

    public String encrypt(String s){
        cc1.set_string_under_action(s);
        cc2.set_string_under_action(s);
        String encrypted1 = cc1.encryptString();
        String encrypted2 = cc2.encryptString();
        String encrypted = CaesarCipher.interleave(encrypted1, encrypted2);
        return encrypted;

    }

    /**
     * Takes a String and decrypts it using 2 keys
     * @param s
     *          String input for decryption
     * @param mode
     *          Accepts either 1 or 2 as input
     *          Mode 1 - Use the complement of key used for encryption while doing decryption. Its critical that this mode be used with the same
     *                   key settings as used while encrypting the String
     *          Mode 2 - The method figures out the right decryption key to be used 
     * @return
     *          Decrypted String
     */

    public String decrypt(String s, int mode){

        String [] decrypt = CaesarCipherTwo.halfOfString(s);
        cc1.set_string_under_action(decrypt[0]);
        cc2.set_string_under_action(decrypt[1]);
        String d1 = cc1.decryptString(mode);
        String d2 = cc2.decryptString(mode);
        String d = CaesarCipherTwo.weaveTwoStrings(d1, d2);
        return d;   
    }

    /**
     * Break a string into 2 (alternate chars in each of the 2 resultant strings)
     * @param s 
     *          Input String
     * @return
     *          Returns an array of 2 strings. These are the resultant strings from breaking the input string
     */

    public static String[] halfOfString(String s){
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(10000);
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(10000);
        String [] decrypt = new String[2];

        for (int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
            if (i%2 == 0){
                sb1.append(s.charAt(i));
            }else {
                sb2.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        decrypt[0] = sb1.toString();
        decrypt[1] = sb2.toString();
        return decrypt;
    }

    /**
     * This method weaves 2 strings together into a single string. Letters from each of the input strings form alternate letters in final string
     * @param s1
     *          First input String
     * @param s2
     *          Second input String
     * @return
     *          Final resultant String
     */

    public static String weaveTwoStrings(String s1,String s2){
        int len = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);

            for (int i=0; i< len; i++){
                if (i < s1.length() && i < s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
                }else if (i < s1.length() && i >= s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
                }else if (i >= s1.length() && i < s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(i)); 
                }
            }        
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `String alphabet` somewhere that *declares* the `alphabet` variable.  You don't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write these variables `alphabet` and `e_alphabet` like a `global` variables like thess:

```
 String alphabet = "";
 String e_alphabet = "";
 private void generateEncryptionLookup(){...
```

Comment: Except that if all he does is declare the identifiers like this, they become useless.  They're local variables in a method, and they're at the end of the method, and they will never be used.  There's something else missing.

Comment: @ejb creating a global variables is a good idea